# GSM, GPRS, GNSS, Bluetooth and RTC Hat

Tags: pi-zero-w, gps

Need pointing in the right direction. Im trying to build a GPS/GSM Tracker I brought this tracker from the Pi shop (https://thepihut.com/products/gsm-gprs-gnss-bluetooth-hat-for-raspberry-pi) for some reason I am unable to get this working. The instructions I'm following are (https://medium.com/@onehitwonder/how-to-build-a-raspberry-pi-gps-tracker-c5e63d456c84) to me it seems that everything has installed correctly, had some problems with installing WiringPi but I got the software install from there website which installed fine. But for some reason I cant see weather the Tracker receiving the message to start the command or not due to this command not working (sudo screen -r pitracker.py)

Has anyone else tried using this tracker? If so what instructions did you follow?

Comment: I didn't look at your links- you should ask your own question. One thing is clear; WiringPi was deprecated by its author 3 years ago.

Comment: It's a waveshare product. Have you checked their Wiki (linked to from the Pihut product page)? Looks like example source code uses serial module; not WiringPi.

Comment: I have been pointed to u-center software to use. How you used this before?